# Authentication CodeIgniter views

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I have a login helper in my CodeIgniter project.
In every constructor of a controller I call a function to check if the user is logged in.
However when calling a function(getSetup) when logged out the login_view appears but also the other view db_manage for example. But I don't want to show content when not logged in.. How to fix this ?

Thanks

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    if (!is_logged_in()) {
        $this->load->view('login_view');
    }
}


public function getSetup() {
    $this->load->view("db_manage");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this way:

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    if (!is_logged_in()) {
        echo $this->load->view('login_view', null, TRUE);
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Still gives the same result , whenever calling exit I get a white screen.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can't exit in the c'tor that will stop Codeigniter from doing its render process from the output buffer.  You can't really do this from the c'tor, its not really what the c'tor is for, its meant for setting up the class variables..

you should check the logged in from the method, and return the login view from there.

```
class My_Controller {
    function ensureLoggedIn() {
        if(!is_logged_in()) {
            $this->load->view('login_view');
            return False;
        }

        return True;
    }

    function getSetup() {
        if(!$this->ensureLoggedIn())
             return;

        .... rest of method ...
    }
}
```

@egig - whats the point in using a framework if your going to bypass the stack?!